# URL Path Rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Maybe this has been answered before, I can't seem to get any thing to work. I am new to rewriting.

What I have is this, http://www.domain.com/path1/path2/path3/page

What I want is to remove only path2 from the url, so the result will be http://www.domain.com/path1/path3/page

How can I achieve this without redirecting?

This is currently what I have:

`RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ $1/$3 [L]`

This is located in my vhost file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your regex to account for everything after the second `path`:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(.+)$ /$1/$3 [L]
```

Also, make sure you turn on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Hm, I tried that; but I'm seeing 404 page. And yes, I have
`RewriteEngine on`

Comment: @user1669346 Then the problem isn't the rules. You want these rules to rewrite to `http://www.domain.com/path1/path3/page`, but if that page gives you a 404, the rules are working correctly, but your links are broken.

Comment: the original path is dynamically created by a cms, so the directories aren't really there. But what I want to do is just to mask the url I want, which is the one with the removed "path2" from the url. Is this possible?